# How to display only end result in while loop PHP?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a problem that I do not know how to solve.  See the below while loop:

```
while($rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
    $grade += $rows2['grade'];
    $total += $rows2['total'];
    $average = ($grade / $total) * 100 . "%";
    ?>
    <tr><td><?php print "$classname"; ?></td><td><?php print "$average"; ?></td></tr>
    <?php
}
```

How can I make it display once the classname and the overall average?

Currently, it displays the classname multiple times and then displays each new average.

Comment: this seems like a homework problem...

Comment: NOTE: Before the while loop:

    $grade = 0;
    $total = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move these outside of the while loop.

```
$average = ($grade / $total) * 100 . "%";

<tr><td><?php print "$classname"; ?></td><td><?php print "$average"; ?></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly you want to do...
but from the variable names I think you would like to calculate the average grade of a particular class and print it out once?

Then you should move `$average = ($grade / $total) * 100 /"%";`
and the `<tr><td><?php print "$classname"; ?></td><td><?php print "$average"; ?></td></tr>`

outside of the while loop (After the while loop).

You are printing the average (not the final result you want) and the classname everytime as you put them in the loop.